# Custom projection in Centimetre (based on EPSG:28350)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to create a custom projection in centimetre based on EPSG:28350 (which is in metre)

What needs to be done ? (it is not displaying correctly on QGIS)

Tried:

- changing the Unit to "centimetre" (from "metre")

## EPSG:28350

```
PROJCS["GDA94 / MGA zone 50",
GEOGCS["GDA94",
    DATUM["Geocentric_Datum_of_Australia_1994",
        SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6283"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4283"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",117],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","28350"]]
```

## EPSG:100001 (My custom CRS)

```
PROJCS["GDA94 / MGA zone 50",
GEOGCS["GDA94",
    DATUM["Geocentric_Datum_of_Australia_1994",
        SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6283"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4283"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",117],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
UNIT["centimetre",1,                     #<--- centimetre instead of metre
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","100001"]]
```

Comment: What software are you using? Please add more details to "not displaying correctly".

Comment: was using QGIS, it is not displaying where i expect it on the map.

Comment: You might want to change the name of your custom projection to note that it is no longer "GDA94 / MGA zone 50". The false easting and northing should now become PARAMETER["false_easting",50000000], PARAMETER["false_northing",1000000000]. And remove AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"].

Comment: magic, it works! thanks @Pointdump

Comment: it worked once, and then it never worked again... using this following proj4 works
+proj=utm +zone=50 +south +ellps=GRS80 +units=cm +no_defs

Comment: You shouldn't prefix it `EPSG:` anything as it's not a code from the [EPSG registry](https://epsg.org)

Comment: cm definition should be 0.01 not 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

the one that works is this proj4 def (changed units to cm)

`+proj=utm +zone=50 +south +ellps=GRS80 +units=cm +no_defs`

based on epsg:28350 proj4 def

`+proj=utm +zone=50 +south +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs`

I can't get WKT definition to work...it worked once and then..never worked again, not sure what happened.